# Past tense passive voice for “être”

Tags: passé-composé, passif

What happens if you are in the past tense and using the verb "être"?

I'm new to this so I'm not even sure if this sentence would make sense.

> Cette ville n'a pas été été célèbre avant que les explorateurs anglais l'ont trouvée.

"été été" looks wrong. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Être* has no passive form… in French as well as in English. “To be been (by something)” doesn't make sense.

Comment: And what about avoire, please?

Comment: 'This cake is to be had by someone who has mastered French'

Comment: Ah, indeed, for a couple of different meanings it's possible in English, but these meanings do not fall under the scope of the French's *avoir*.

Comment: Okay, so you can have the cake now :-D